# How do I make a specific column 0

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE ingredient
(
    inId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    inName VARCHAR(30),
    inSupplier VARCHAR(30),
    inPrice double,
    inStock INT,
    imageFile VARCHAR(100)
);
```

I want to make inStock column 0 to all rows in the table.
Do I use alter or update or set?

Comment: You should use `update` and `set` like this: `UPDATE ingredient SET inStock=0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an `update` statement without a `where` clause:

```sql
UPDATE ingredient
SET    inStock = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

For set all exists record to 0 (zero) use query:

```
UPDATE ingredient SET inStock = 0;
```

For sure default value 0 (zero) for new inserted rows alter your table as:

```
ALTER TABLE `ingredient` CHANGE `inStock` `inStock` INT(11) DEFAULT 0 NULL;
```

or create table using:

```
CREATE TABLE ingredient
(
    inId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    inName VARCHAR(30),
    inSupplier VARCHAR(30),
    inPrice DOUBLE,
    inStock INT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    imageFile VARCHAR(100)
);
```